# control of an integral using the integral of derivative

Tags: real-analysis

Let $J$ be an interval and $f$ be a good function. Prove: 
$$\inf_c\int_J |f(x)-c| dx\le |J|\int_J|f'(x)|dx$$ where $|J|$ is the length of $J$.

I don't know how to introduce the derivative. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $J=[x_0,x_1]$ and that $f$ is $C^1(J)$.

Then $f(x)-f(x_0) = \int_{x_0}^x f'(t) dt$, and so
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{x_0}^{x_1} |f(x)-f(x_0)| dx &=& \int_{x=x_0}^{x_1} |\int_{t=x_0}^x f'(t) dt |dx \\
&\le& \int_{x=x_0}^{x_1} \int_{t=x_0}^x |f'(t)| dt dx \\
&=& \int_{t=x_0}^{x_1} \int_{x=t}^{x_1} |f'(t)| dt dx \\
&\le& (x_1-x_0)\int_{t=x_0}^{x_1} |f'(t)| dt \\
\end{eqnarray}

Since $\inf_c\int_J |f(x)-c| dx \le \int_{x_0}^{x_1} |f(x)-f(x_0)| dx$, we
obtain the desired result.

The result extends to other types of intervals by taking limits.